# Copying multiple rows/colums from ListBox to excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I need a serious help. The code below works out of the box for one simple ListBox but the problem is that my listbox has 7 column that I need to copy to excel. I know that the solution is probably easy but I have no idea how to modify it to make it work. Right now is copying the first column only

```
Private Sub CopyButton_Click()

Dim i As Long
Dim ary


    ReDim ary(0 To 0)

    With Me.ListBox2
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then

            ReDim Preserve ary(1 To UBound(ary) + 1)

            ary(UBound(ary)) = .List(i)
        End If
    Next
    End With


    Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(ary)).Value _
    = Application.Transpose(ary)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The ListBox List Property returns an array all of the values in the ListBox.

```
With Me.ListBox2
    Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(.ListCount, .ColumnCount).Value = .List
End With
```

The easiest way to copy the Selected items into an Array is to:

1. Loop through the items
2. Dimension the Array to fit
3. Make a second loop filling the Array

This will prevent you from having to Transpose the Array.

---

```
Private Sub CopyButton_Click()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, count As Long
    Dim ary As Variant

    With Me.ListBox2
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next
        ReDim ary(1 To count, 1 To .ColumnCount)
        count = 0
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then
                count = count + 1
                For j = 0 To .ColumnCount - 1
                    ary(count, j + 1) = .List(i, j)
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With

    Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(ary, 1), UBound(ary, 2)).Value = ary

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, your code returns all data within ListBox2. I need to copy only what is inside the array. I just don't know how to modify the array to paste all columns from the selected rows. Thank you again

Comment: @Ernesto Sorry that I missed it.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate this code. I wish i had the skills. Thank you again

Comment: You should watch this series: [Excel VBA Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHO5NIcZAc4&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).  It will teach you the skills.